# Recovering files from a failed ext4 partition resize

Tags: linux, partitioning, ext4

I didn't know a resize operation on a 750 GB disk was going to take 40+ hours, and I was biting my nails the whole time, until the power went out when "only" 8 hours where left...

I can still mount the partition, and many of the files are still there, but some files show as '? ? ? ? ? filename.ext' with `ls -l`.

If I try to go inside such a directory: `Input/output error`.

Are those files lost?

Comment: I just tried photorec and it works, but it also "recovers" files that aren't lost, and files that I don't need. It would take ages to process the entire disk, plus I don't have space in another partition to put all the recovered files, so I only want to recover some of the dirs if at all possible.

Comment: Saw your comment after I posted my answer below. I believe you'll find the same results from most if not all file recovery software, although something designed specifically for ext4 (e.g. extundelete) *may* be able to read the file system's meta data to look only within certain directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, I've seen this, on a corrupted ext4 partition no less. (Actually, I thought it was a failed hard drive, and rushed out and bought a whole set of new ones, only to later discover the drives were all fine after all, but that's another story.) You may have success with a utility like [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/), but I'd wager most if not all of those files are good and gone.

You've got backups though, right? ;-) (I poke fun, but only because I've been there before, which is why I now have a pretty darned thorough backup system.)

Comment: extundelete looked promising with its `restore-directory` and `restore-files` options, but no dice :( The files aren't that important so I guess I'll just let it go. PD: I do have backups for my important files, Dropbox FTW!